# I am getting an error: "Unexpected token <" in a javascript file that i used as part of an online banking project.I have attached the file below

Tags: javascript, token

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

            function num_only()
                    {
                        var keyASCII = window.event.keyCode;
                        var keyValue = String.fromCharCode(keyASCII);
                            if (!(keyValue >= '0' && keyValue <= '9'))
                                {
                                    window.event.keyCode=0;
                                    alert ("please enter numeric value");
                                }
                    }
function check()
    {
        var td=document.dfrm.tdd.value; var tm=document.dfrm.tmm.value; var ty=document.dfrm.tyy.value;
        var fd=document.dfrm.fdd.value; var fm=document.dfrm.fmm.value; var fy=document.dfrm.fyy.value; 
        if(td=="" ){
            alert("Please Enter All Fields");
            //td.select();
            return false;
            } 
        else if(tm=="" ){
            alert("Please Enter All Fields");
            //tm.select();
            return false;
            } 

        else if (ty=="") {
            alert("Please Enter All Fields");
            //ty.select();
            return false;
            } 

        else if(fd=="") {
            alert("Please Enter All Fields");
            //fd.select();
            return false;
            } 
         else if(fm=="" ){
            alert("Please Enter All Fields");
            //fm.select();
            return false;
            } 
            else if( fy==""){
            alert("Please Enter All Fields");
            //fy.select();
            return false;
            } 
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help in your code.** Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO and read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to ask a question. **What is your question?**

Comment: if what you posted is the content of a .js file, remove `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">` - you don't need a HTML tag in a script file

Comment: Did it tell you a line number? I'm pretty sure it would have, and it would have said line one, column one.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the verbatim copy of your Javascript file, remove the script tags surrounding your script.

The script tags are not valid JS and are only used in HTML files.